# How can i get the data of the input hidden field whose name equals to a method and a string in java

Tags: java, jsp

Here is a sample jsp page with a form.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="h.abc" %>
<%
    abc p = new abc();
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="abcd.jsp" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="<%=p.getName()%>+'Name'" value='y'>
            <input type='text' name='<%=p.getName()%>' >
            <input type='submit' value='submit'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the abc class in the 'h' package.Please pardon the naming.It's only for illustration purposes.

```
public class abc {
    public String name="abc";
    public abc()
    {

    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And this is the abcd.jsp target page.Here i am trying to get the value of the input field.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="h.abc" %>


<%
    abc p = new abc();
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% 
            String s = p.getName();
            out.println(request.getParameter(s+"Name"));
            out.println(request.getParameter(s));
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am unable comprehend why the input field is not returning 'y' as its value.rather it is returning null.

Comment: add the method where you set the parameter(or the controller method)

Comment: Above is the complete code.There is no other method.I am able to get the data of the input text field but the  hidden field returns null.if i run the above pages using apache tomcat.The output is as follow:
null "Whatever we enter in input field".

Comment: check your first jsp and view the source code of it,I think in the first jsp page the name is called `abcName`,but in the second page the name differs depends on what you input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the code in first jsp

```html
<input type="hidden" name="<%=p.getName()%>Name" value='y'>
```

Comment: Firstly,i guess even if the objects are different the string they return i.e String returned via getName() will be the same.so i should be able to get the data of the input field.If i am wrong then how can i solve the above situation.

Comment: change your code first jsp--<input type="hidden" name="<%=p.getName()%>Name" value='y'>

Comment: In this main problem is string concatenation is mismatch first jsp to second jsp

Comment: how can i get the data of the input field <input type="hidden" name="<%=p.getName()%>+'Name'" value='y'> .
and what do i change in the code?Above is a question representing the problem that i face in my project.

Comment: you dont need to put single quotes with Name

Answer (score 0):

you need put your abc instance in HttpServletRequest'attributes by calling setAttribute("you_key", abcInstance) method. And then you can get abc instance in your jsp pages by calling req.getAttribute("your_key") or using el expression

Comment: i did try to set attribute like this. request.setAttribute("ins", p); in the page where form resides and then in the target page abcd.jsp page when i try to get the abc instance like abc obj =(abc)request.getAttribute("ins"); and call the getName() it throws a nullpointerexception.
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: exception occurred at line 22
19:     </head>
20:     <body>
21:         <% 
22:             String s = obj.getName();
23:             out.println(request.getParameter(s+"Name"));
24:             out.println(request.getParameter(s));
25:         %>